# How to INNER JOIN and OUTER JOIN within the same table?

Tags: join, subquery

I am using PostgreSQL and I have the following tables:

1. Product

   ```
   ID | Name | Price
   ```
2. Receipts

   ```
   ID | Month | Quantity | Product_ID (FK)
   ```
3. Sales

   ```
   ID | Month | Quantity | Product_ID (FK)
   ```

I am trying to come up with a query that displays something like this:

```
    Month | Product.Name | Amount received | Amount sold
```

It is very important to keep in mind that there can be more than one receipt or sale of the same product on the same month. I need to come up with a query that tells me the amount received and the amount sold of a particular product on a each month.  It is possible that a product is not sold in a month (that's why the **OUTER JOIN** below).

The best that I've got so far is this:

```
    SELECT s.month, p.name, r.quantity, SUM(s.quantity)
    FROM product AS p
    INNER JOIN receipts AS r
       ON p.id_product = r.product_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN sales AS s
       ON p.id_product = v.product_id 
    GROUP BY s.month, p.name, r.quantity
```

Let's say in the same month there were 2 receipts of keyboards. The first one with 100 keyboards and the second one with 50 keyboards. Also, there was a sale of 10 keyboards and then another one of 20 keyboards.

An example of what is returned by this query:

```
     Month | Product.Name | Amount received | Amount sold
       6   |   Keyboard   |       100       |    30
       6   |   Keyboard   |       50        |    30
```

This one works fine when there are mutiple sales (apart from the repetition) but not when there are multiple receipts. I was thinking that I should relate s.month and r.month with an INNER JOIN, but I don't know how.

Sorry for the bunch of information at once. If there is anything unclear, let me know.
Can anyone help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: Is it `product.id` or `product.id_product`? The code does not match the description. And why don't you have the same (`product_id`) name for the column everywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is joining 2 tables (receipts, sales) that both have a many-to-one relationship with `product`. This creates a kind of cartesian (cross) product and will give wrong results in the `SUM()` calculations. To avoid that, you need to do the summations for the two tables in two different subqueries to avoid errors.

Something like this will work:

```
SELECT 
    m.month, 
    p.name, 
    COALESCE(r.receipts_quantity, 0) AS receipts_quantity, 
    COALESCE(s.sales_quantity, 0)    AS sales_quantity
FROM 
    product AS p
  CROSS JOIN
    ( VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6) ) AS m(month)     -- months wanted in the report
  LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    ( SELECT month, product_id, SUM(quantity) AS receipts_quantity
      FROM receipts
      GROUP BY month, product_id
    ) AS r
    ON  p.id_product = r.product_id
    AND m.month = r.month
  LEFT OUTER JOIN  
    ( SELECT month, product_id, SUM(quantity) AS sales_quantity
      FROM sales
      GROUP BY month, product_id
    ) AS s
    ON  p.id_product = s.product_id
    AND m.month = s.month ;
```

If you want to avoid having results for products that did not have any activity in a month, you can add the condition:

```
WHERE r.month IS NOT NULL 
   OR s.month IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks, ypercube, apparently it works. The only thing is that on the result, when I set VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6) for months, there are rows even for the months when there is no correspondent receipts or sales registered. How can I avoid that? In fact, could you explain a little more why the CROSS JOIN is necessary?

Comment: Worked just fine :) Thank you very much!!!